# Is there any way to make each 3 letters unique group of array from a string in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

For example:
I have a string like:

```
val string = "abc"
```

Now I want to convert it to an array like this:

```
val myArray = arrayOf("abc", "acb", "bac", "bca", "cab", "cba" )
```

Comment: What you are looking for called Permutation. It s a math question and there is no official function or support that could give you what you want. You may take a look at existant algorithms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin generate permutations (in order) of list without duplicate elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59715608/kotlin-generate-permutations-in-order-of-list-without-duplicate-elements)